# How to get text outside the div?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="amlocator-store-information" style="" xpath="1"> 
  <div class="amlocator-title" style="">The Better Health Store</div>
  2420 E-Stadium Ann Arbor MI 48104
  <br><br>
  (613) 975-6613
  <div style="" class="amasty_distance" id="amasty_distance_1">Distance:                            
    <span class="amasty_distance_number"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using selenium with python and trying to get the address from the DOM but I can't,
I have used

```
store_block_list  = '//div[@class="amlocator-store-information"]'
store_block_list = '//div[@class="amlocator-title"]'
```

to capture the elements but cant get the address out as you can see the address is outside the //div element
Please note it is a list of elements and I then use for loop to loop around the element list

Comment: The locator "//div[@class="amlocator-store-information"]" should get you the right div, and you can't capture that text?

Comment: @DMart when I use the element.text, I get "The Better Health Store 2420 E-Stadium Ann Arbor MI 48104 (613) 975-6613 Distance: 600 mi" I cant rely on reverse slicing because 600 mile can change to 5000 which I am assuming will mess the indexes I am tryin to capture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the address i.e. **2420 E-Stadium Ann Arbor MI 48104** as it is a *Text Node* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` using `execute_script()` method and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.amlocator-store-information")))).strip())
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='amlocator-store-information']")))).strip())
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: This worked, but it was slow I guess because of almost 2000 elements, is execute_script the only method to sue for this case? anything faster?
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
storeElement = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, store_block_list)))
full_list = []
for store in storeElement:
    print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', store).strip())

Comment: @Ronron Can't comment why it was slow without seeing the relevant HTML, WebDriver configuration, network speed, bandwidth and the version of the binaries you are using. However, it is to be noted we have opted for the condition `visibility_of_all_elements_located` which is mandatory before you attempt to grab the desired text from the _Text Node_.

Comment: Why are you using the execute_script?