# How to extract the text 121.6 from the text node within the span tag using Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

For the following element on the web

```
<span title="点赞数14332" class="like"><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><i class="van-icon-videodetails_like" style="color:;"></i>1.4万
    </span>
```

```
<span title="number" class="like">
   <!---->
   <!---->
   <!---->
   <!---->
   <!---->
   <i class="van-icon-videodetails_like" style="color:;"></i>
"121.6"
</span>
```

What I want to get is the number "121.6".
I tried,

`likes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="like"]')[0].text`

It returns me "--", and nothing else.

I also tried to copy the X-path from the inspection,

```
likes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="arc_toolbar_report"]/div[1]/span[1]/text()')
```

But selenium returns me:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[@id="arc_toolbar_report"]/div[1]/span[1]/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

What should I do to get the number "121.6"?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the number of *Likes* on the video i.e. the current text as **1.5万** as the text is within a *Text Node* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and `execute_script()` method and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='like' and starts-with(@title, '点赞数')][not(contains(.,'--'))]")))).strip())
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.like[title^='点赞数']")))).strip())
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to get text outside the div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60288910/how-to-get-text-outside-the-div/60289318#60289318)
- [Protractor Conditional Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62043616/protractor-conditional-selector/62043910#62043910)

Comment: It still return's me '--' instead of the number

Comment: @XiangboGao Did you try both the _xpath_ and _Css_

Comment: Yes I did. For CSS, since title is not always 'number'. I used ```span.like``` instead. That is not the problem, right?

Comment: It is a chinese website. https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV18K4y1t7De and the full X-path is this, if you want to look it up /html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/span[1]/text()

Comment: And please look it up. I am very new in selenium and I am struggling in this for hours

Comment: Oh, if you are still working on this problem. Just to mention that the number I want to get is dynamic. It changes over time. May be that is why we cannot get it? on another X-path, there is a number which is inside the <div>, but I still got '--', instead of the actually number.

Comment: @XiangboGao Instead of handcrafted HTML update the question with text based actual HTML.

Comment: Now, it has been updated. It that what you are looking for?

Comment: @XiangboGao Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your provided xpath and your link to [bilibili.com](https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV18K4y1t7De) and was able to get the number of likes for that video. As already mentioned in [DebanjanB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62058678/11057157) you will have to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808).

Your code returned '--' because the amount of likes were still dynamically being loaded in the background. Below you will find a code snippet that waits for the '--' to be replaced by an actual number

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/span[1] \
    [not(contains(text(),"--"))]')
))

likes = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/span[1]").text
print(likes)
```

which returns 1.4万

The

> [not(contains(text(),"--"))]

basically tells the driver to wait until the selected node does not contain the '--' string.

**EDIT:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

These are the imports which you will need.